# TF tutorial crash

Tags: ros, tutorial, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm following this tutorial
http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials/Introduction%20to%20tf

The last step in the launch file

```
  <node name="turtle_pointer" pkg="turtle_tf" type="turtle_tf_listener.py" respawn="false" output="screen" >
  </node>
```

systematically fails:

```
[turtle_pointer-6] process has died [pid 4833, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/geometry_tutorials/turtle_tf/nodes/turtle_tf_listener.py __name:=turtle_pointer __log:=/home/erupter/.ros/log/a1d3b986-354a-11e2-9db2-d49a205b33a5/turtle_pointer-6.log].
log file: /home/erupter/.ros/log/a1d3b986-354a-11e2-9db2-d49a205b33a5/turtle_pointer-6*.log
```

here is the log content

```
[rospy.client][INFO] 2012-11-23 09:49:05,206: init_node, name[/turtle_pointer], pid[4833]
[xmlrpc][INFO] 2012-11-23 09:49:05,207: XML-RPC server binding to 0.0.0.0
[xmlrpc][INFO] 2012-11-23 09:49:05,207: Started XML-RPC server [http://FCD-04-Ubuntu:38834/]
[rospy.init][INFO] 2012-11-23 09:49:05,207: ROS Slave URI: [http://FCD-04-Ubuntu:38834/]
[rospy.impl.masterslave][INFO] 2012-11-23 09:49:05,208: _ready: http://FCD-04-Ubuntu:38834/
[xmlrpc][INFO] 2012-11-23 09:49:05,208: xml rpc node: starting XML-RPC server
[rospy.registration][INFO] 2012-11-23 09:49:05,209: Registering with master node http://localhost:11311
[rospy.init][INFO] 2012-11-23 09:49:05,308: registered with master
[rospy.rosout][INFO] 2012-11-23 09:49:05,308: initializing /rosout core topic
[rospy.rosout][INFO] 2012-11-23 09:49:05,313: connected to core topic /rosout
[rospy.simtime][INFO] 2012-11-23 09:49:05,316: /use_sim_time is not set, will not subscribe to simulated time [/clock] topic
[rospy.internal][INFO] 2012-11-23 09:49:05,331: topic[/tf] adding connection to [http://FCD-04-Ubuntu:42239/], count 0
[rospy.internal][INFO] 2012-11-23 09:49:05,501: topic[/rosout] adding connection to [/rosout], count 0
[rospy.internal][INFO] 2012-11-23 09:49:05,536: topic[/tf] adding connection to [http://FCD-04-Ubuntu:50740/], count 1
[rospy.core][INFO] 2012-11-23 09:49:05,574: signal_shutdown [atexit]
[rospy.internal][INFO] 2012-11-23 09:49:05,577: topic[/rosout] removing connection to /rosout
[rospy.internal][INFO] 2012-11-23 09:49:05,578: topic[/tf] removing connection to http://FCD-04-Ubuntu:42239/
[rospy.internal][INFO] 2012-11-23 09:49:05,578: topic[/tf] removing connection to http://FCD-04-Ubuntu:50740/
[rospy.impl.masterslave][INFO] 2012-11-23 09:49:05,578: atexit
```

So I edited in the launch file the last node and removed the .py from turtle_tf_listener.py
This way it doesn't crash anymore but I have these

```
[ INFO] [1353660856.840262559]: waitForService: Service [/spawn] has not been advertised, waiting...
[ INFO] [1353660856.928373839]: waitForService: Service [/spawn] is now available.
[ERROR] [1353660857.031546679]: Frame id /turtle2 does not exist! Frames (1):
```

and I can't get past this.

Also why when I use a launch file my master is not accessible from other terminals as it always is?
Meaning that when I launch this launch file, open another terminal for example to use rxgraph, this can't find the master although it's at the usual URI
http://localhost:11311

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48908/tf-tutorial-crash/) by [Claudio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3152/claudio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 859 on 2012-11-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There looks to be a regression in waitForTransform: https://github.com/ros/geometry_experimental/issues/102 please help track this down on the ticket.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0